# How to prevent code behind function from being activated with js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

The problem:

I have a form with a code behind function and i also make some js validtions and i don't want the code behind funciton to work if the js returns false.
I have tried to use OnClientClick and return false at the end of the function but i didn't work.

aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
  CssClass="action-button" 
  OnClientClick="return updateValidation();"  
  OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Update" />
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Update : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack && Session["user"] != null)
        {

            UserService us = new UserService();
            string id = Session["user"] as string;
            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = '" + id + "'";
            DataTable table = us.ExecuteDataTable(selectQuery);

            SignUpName.Value = table.Rows[0]["fName"] as string;
            SignUpLastName.Value = table.Rows[0]["lName"] as string;
            email.Value = table.Rows[0]["email"] as string;
            birthDate.Value = table.Rows[0]["birthDate"] as string;
            city.Value = table.Rows[0]["city"] as string;
            address.Value = table.Rows[0]["address"] as string;
            zipCode.Value = table.Rows[0]["zipcode"] as string;
            Password.Value = table.Rows[0]["userPassword"] as string;
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
            string id = Session["user"] as string;
            string fName = SignUpName.Value.ToString();
            string lName = SignUpLastName.Value.ToString();
            string UserbirthDate = birthDate.Value.ToString();
            string Usercity = city.Value.ToString();
            string UserAddress = address.Value.ToString();
            string UserZipCode = zipCode.Value.ToString();
            string UserEmail = email.Value.ToString();
            string userPassword = Password.Value.ToString();
            UserService us = new UserService();
            User u = new User(fName, lName, id, UserbirthDate, Usercity, UserAddress, UserZipCode, UserEmail, userPassword);

            us.UpdateUser(u);
        
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
function updateValidation() {        

    window.check = true;
    checkFName();
    checkLName();
    checkEmail();
    checkBrithDate();
    checkCity();
    checkAddress();
    checkZipCode();
    checkPassword();

    return check;

}
```

I have already tried returning false at the end of the js at any case but it didn't work either.

Comment: your code is correct, but you do not actually return the `windows.check` ! you return just `check` that is not false or true. Also if you have any javascript errors also the return check is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The code is structured fine and your `window.check` variable has a `boolean` value but instead of that, you are returning a variable named `check` which I do not see declared or being modified anywhere in your code example. Which means, the `check` variable does not have a `boolean` value, rather it has `undefined` or `null` in it.

See:

```
function updateValidation() {
    window.check = true;
    checkFName();
    checkLName();
    checkEmail();
    checkBrithDate();
    checkCity();
    checkAddress();
    checkZipCode();
    checkPassword();
    // Instead of just returning check, return window.check
    return window.check;

}
```

If that does not work either, then it is certain that the `boolean` is always `true` which doesn't stop the post back.

Also, you can use `jquery` to bind the event which is my preferred way of binding the events:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
  CssClass="action-button" 
  OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Update" />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#<%= Button1.ClientID %>').on('click', function(){
        window.check = true;
        checkFName();
        checkLName();
        checkEmail();
        checkBrithDate();
        checkCity();
        checkAddress();
        checkZipCode();
        checkPassword();
        // Instead of returning check, return window.check
        return window.check;
    });
    // Your Javascript functions go here...
});
```

Notice, I have removed the `OnClientClick` event from the button markup, and have bound the event directly to the element which is better than returning the `boolean` value twice, one in the method itself and the second in the button markup.

---

**UPDATE**

I suspect that your `window.check` object is undefined. Which is why it is returning an `undefined` instead of a boolean value. I would recommend you to replace `window.check` with just a global variable `check` like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var check; // declare a variable named check in global scope to the click event
    $('#<%= Button1.ClientID %>').on('click', function(){
        check = true; // set the initial value
        checkFName();
        checkLName();
        checkEmail();
        checkBrithDate();
        checkCity();
        checkAddress();
        checkZipCode();
        checkPassword();
 
        return check; // return the variable check instead of window.check
    });
    // Your Javascript functions go here...
});
```

Comment: I have tried it and even returning false at the end of the js anyway but it still didn't work. The Code Behind function is still being activated

Comment: Please try to check the value of `window.check`. I suspect that it is `undefined` that is why the `CodeBehind` is being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You should to call the function Button1_Click after the function updateValidaton.
You can do it this way:
In the button element, replace the Button1_Click with function myFunction (or ahatever you and it to be called). Then:
function myFunction(){ if (updateValidation()) Button1_Click(); }

It will call the Button1_Click function only if the validation returns true.

Comment: js. I dont think you can call a js function from behind

Comment: but onClick also work with js functions ..? not only onclientclick ?

Comment: it returns an error that my page doesn't have a definition for myFunction

Answer (score -2):

Change the ASPX to the following (note the `event` passed to the JS function and removed `return`):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
  CssClass="action-button" 
  OnClientClick="updateValidation(event);"  
  OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Update" />
```

If `window.check` is a global bool parameter then check it in the JS function and prevent the submit event (note the `event`):

```
function updateValidation(event) {        

    window.check = true;
    checkFName();
    checkLName();
    checkEmail();
    checkBrithDate();
    checkCity();
    checkAddress();
    checkZipCode();
    checkPassword();

    if (window.check == false) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    return check;
}
```

Generally you should be using the built in WebForms validators to get this accomplished, you can read about it here: https://www.codemag.com/Article/0307101/Validating-Data-On-Web-Forms

Comment: I have copied your code but the code behind function is still being activated at any case.

Comment: @nettqbbrq verify the value of `window.check` variable is false otherwise it won't enter the `if` statement.

Comment: I even tried to do event.preventDefault(); if it's not false and it didnt work

Comment: @nettqbbrq if all you want is to prevent the button from submitting in all cases then move the `event.preventDefault()` outside of the `if` statement, or even as the first statement in the JS function, make sure you copied the ASPX code

Comment: but how can i do it outside of the if statement if i only want it it happen in certain situations..?

Comment: `window.check` needs to be `false` so the `if` statement enters and prevents the submit, does it work when it's the first line?

Comment: when it's the first line it work but i can't do at the first line. Is there any solution ?

Comment: @nettqbbrq need to make sure that `window.check` is false, use the browser developer tools and debugger, set a break point on the `if` line and check that variable.
Please read here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints

Comment: I have checked that is false but it didn't work in case that this is not the first line and i can't place at at the first line.

Comment: @nettqbbrq without more details showing what you tried it's impossible to help without knowing what you tried now, edit the question and add more details.